# Bootstrap Carousel slow transition Bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have some problem with a Twitter Bootstrap carousel. If i set the carousel transition between the slides on 1 or more seconds, i can see some flickering between the transitions.

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
    -webkit-transition:2.6s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition:2.6s ease-in-out left;
    transition:2.6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

I don't really know how can i fix that, here is the axample of that issue: http://jsfiddle.net/z3fe1tzm/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem, what browser are you using?

Comment: i have tried that in safari 8, firefox 38 and google chrome 43.

Comment: Weird, it looks good on my computer, what do you mean by "flickering"?

Comment: I mean the left image disappears at the begin of sliding to right http://i.stack.imgur.com/rUTS9.png

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I can confirm I see the behavior as well.  The left image disappears while sliding if the transitions are `> .7s` for me.

Comment: ok, yes I do see that.

Comment: @OhBeWise thank you for your answer, yes it's really weird... and it seems to be a bootstrap bug :(